# A lot of TCP retransmissions on virtual interfaces when sending large amounts of data

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

For some time I have strange network lags when using virtual NICs created by VPNs like ZeroTier and Hamachi, especially when sending large amounts of data. I use Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-67-generic.

Wireshark shows a lot of TCP retransmissions, ACK dupes and out-of-order packets.

```
1   0.000000000 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 74  44602 → 25565 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=63480 Len=0 MSS=2760 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2974512735 TSecr=0 WS=128
2   0.045201707 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 62  25565 → 44602 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=0 MSS=2760 SACK_PERM=1
3   0.045262797 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=0
4   0.049124813 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 74  44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=20
5   0.049473924 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 65  44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=21 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=11
6   0.093782891 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=0
7   0.096647589 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 58  25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=4
8   0.096672987 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=5 Win=63476 Len=0
9   0.096770408 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 82  25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=5 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=28
10  0.096783346 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0
11  0.138199037 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 149 [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2793 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=95
12  0.138217852 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  [TCP Dup ACK 10#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0 SLE=2793 SRE=2888
13  0.138274049 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 81  25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2888 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=27
14  0.138281634 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  [TCP Dup ACK 10#2] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0 SLE=2793 SRE=2915
15  0.138309371 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 59  25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2915 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=5
16  0.138315649 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  [TCP Dup ACK 10#3] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0 SLE=2793 SRE=2920
17  0.138342033 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 66  25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2920 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=12
18  0.138348253 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  [TCP Dup ACK 10#4] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0 SLE=2793 SRE=2932
19  0.138374146 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 58  25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2932 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=4 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
20  0.138380017 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  [TCP Dup ACK 10#5] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0 SLE=2793 SRE=2936
21  0.139014360 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Fast Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=33 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=2760
22  0.139025513 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=2936 Win=60720 Len=0
23  0.141892063 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=2936 Ack=32 Win=63449 Len=2760 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
24  0.141913064 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=32 Ack=5696 Win=60720 Len=0
25  0.303248158 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 68  44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=32 Ack=5696 Win=60720 Len=14
26  0.303554866 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 81  44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=46 Ack=5696 Win=60720 Len=27
27  0.303716262 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 59  44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=73 Ack=5696 Win=60720 Len=5
28  0.349692404 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=32380 Ack=73 Win=63408 Len=0
29  0.402913460 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=32380 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=0
30  1.101234508 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=5696 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
31  1.101261884 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=8456 Win=60720 Len=0
32  1.147180805 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=32380 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
33  1.147213877 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  [TCP Dup ACK 31#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=8456 Win=60720 Len=0 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
34  3.300628848 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=8456 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
35  3.300676657 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 66  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=11216 Win=60720 Len=0 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
36  3.350777564 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=37900 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
37  3.350813605 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 74  [TCP Dup ACK 35#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=11216 Win=60720 Len=0 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
38  4.313838376 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=11216 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
39  4.313878478 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 74  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=13976 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
40  4.360138604 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=43420 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
41  4.360199131 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 82  [TCP Dup ACK 39#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=13976 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
42  5.325241275 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=13976 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
43  5.325266889 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 82  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=16736 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
44  5.371542444 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=48940 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
45  5.371570142 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Dup ACK 43#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=16736 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
46  5.724447336 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=16736 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
47  5.724488523 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=19496 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
50  6.079468803 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=19496 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
51  6.079512860 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=22256 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
52  7.039116534 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=22256 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
53  7.039152631 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=25016 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
54  7.053728613 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 94  44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=78 Ack=25016 Win=57960 Len=4 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
55  7.053890617 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 126 44602 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=82 Ack=25016 Win=57960 Len=36 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660 SLE=32380 SRE=35140
56  7.087735464 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=65500 Ack=78 Win=63403 Len=2760
57  7.087768694 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Dup ACK 53#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=25016 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660
58  7.150668480 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=33296 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=0
59  7.444215482 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=25016 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
60  7.444256497 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=27776 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660
61  8.398822152 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=27776 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
62  8.398869702 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=30536 Win=52440 Len=0 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180 SLE=37900 SRE=40660
63  8.447356900 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=76540 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
64  8.447393248 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Dup ACK 62#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=30536 Win=52440 Len=0 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700 SLE=43420 SRE=46180
65  8.810606201 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=30536 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
66  8.810641092 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=35140 Win=52440 Len=0 SLE=32380 SRE=33296 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700
67  8.856490459 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 330 [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=40660 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=276
68  8.856514714 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Window Update] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=35140 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=40660 SRE=40936 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700
69  9.775748115 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=35140 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
70  9.775791032 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 82  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=40936 Win=52440 Len=0 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700
71  9.821968969 172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=87580 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
72  9.821992406 172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Window Update] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=40936 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260 SLE=48940 SRE=51700
73  10.176466157    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=40936 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
74  10.176511928    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=46180 Win=52440 Len=0 SLE=43420 SRE=43696 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260
75  10.533491944    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=46180 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
76  10.533531151    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 82  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=51700 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260
79  11.487938977    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=51700 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
80  11.487983949    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 82  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=54460 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260
81  11.533904915    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=104140 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
82  11.533940582    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Dup ACK 80#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=54460 Win=57960 Len=0 SLE=104140 SRE=106900 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260
83  11.885482472    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=54460 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
84  11.885521789    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=57220 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=104140 SRE=106900 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260
85  12.853577770    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=57220 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
86  12.853620652    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=59980 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=104140 SRE=106900 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300 SLE=65500 SRE=68260
87  12.906044223    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Window Full] [TCP Previous segment not captured] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=112420 Ack=118 Win=63363 Len=2760
88  12.906065406    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  [TCP Dup ACK 86#1] 44602 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=118 Ack=59980 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=112420 SRE=115180 SLE=104140 SRE=106900 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300
89  12.981535818    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 90  44602 → 25565 [FIN, ACK] Seq=118 Ack=59980 Win=55200 Len=0 SLE=112420 SRE=115180 SLE=104140 SRE=106900 SLE=87580 SRE=90340 SLE=76540 SRE=79300
90  13.026084367    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44602 [ACK] Seq=115180 Ack=119 Win=63363 Len=0
91  13.057004830    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 74  44606 → 25565 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=63480 Len=0 MSS=2760 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2974525792 TSecr=0 WS=128
92  13.101638708    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 62  25565 → 44606 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=0 MSS=2760 SACK_PERM=1
93  13.101687138    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=0
94  13.103774881    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 74  44606 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=20
95  13.103992979    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 56  44606 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=21 Ack=1 Win=63480 Len=2
96  13.155155809    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44606 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=23 Win=63458 Len=0
97  13.577219433    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    25565 → 44606 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=23 Win=63458 Len=2760
98  13.577258814    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=23 Ack=2761 Win=60720 Len=0
99  13.869278968    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    [TCP Retransmission] 25565 → 44602 [PSH, ACK] Seq=59980 Ack=119 Win=63363 Len=2760
100 13.869308377    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44602 → 25565 [RST] Seq=119 Win=0 Len=0
101 14.544962843    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    25565 → 44606 [ACK] Seq=2761 Ack=23 Win=63458 Len=2760
102 14.544993395    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=23 Ack=5521 Win=60720 Len=0
103 15.501396856    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2814    25565 → 44606 [ACK] Seq=5521 Ack=23 Win=63458 Len=2760
104 15.501426755    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=23 Ack=8281 Win=60720 Len=0
105 15.551232714    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 2656    25565 → 44606 [PSH, ACK] Seq=8281 Ack=23 Win=63458 Len=2602
106 15.551258749    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=23 Ack=10883 Win=60720 Len=0
107 15.554164780    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 64  44606 → 25565 [PSH, ACK] Seq=23 Ack=10883 Win=60720 Len=10
108 15.600773646    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 64  25565 → 44606 [PSH, ACK] Seq=10883 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=10
109 15.600819407    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [ACK] Seq=33 Ack=10893 Win=60720 Len=0
110 15.600929437    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44606 [FIN, ACK] Seq=10893 Ack=33 Win=63448 Len=0
111 15.601400939    172.27.0.110    172.27.0.179    TCP 54  44606 → 25565 [FIN, ACK] Seq=33 Ack=10894 Win=60720 Len=0
112 15.646026620    172.27.0.179    172.27.0.110    TCP 54  25565 → 44606 [ACK] Seq=10894 Ack=34 Win=63448 Len=0
```

I have tried:

- Rebooting many times
- Restarting ZeroTier
- Reinstalling ZeroTier
- Re-adding myself to ZT network
- https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018696
- Installing updates, including 2 kernel updates
- Resetting NetworkManager to defaults

I want to avoid:

- Reinstalling the whole system

Answer (score 0):

it might be an issue with the linux tun/tap driver (or the way it is implemented in zerotier/hamachi), which I believe is what zerotier uses and is possibly what hamachi uses as well. see [this](https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/issues/1422) and [this](https://discuss.zerotier.com/t/questions-about-bandwidth-and-ipv6/6335/5)